# Value of type 'Messaging' has no member 'shouldEstablishDirectChannel' after updating to Xcode 12

Tags: swift, ios14, xcode12

I m getting Value of type 'Messaging' has no member 'shouldEstablishDirectChannel' error in Xcode 12 does any one facing similar error?

Error is showing in : Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true

Comment: Is it because you update to XCode 12 or because you also did a `pod update`?

Comment: I have upgraded Xcode and pod install

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you did a `pod update` as well or got the latest pod version of Firebase via `pod install` without specifying the version.

Take a look at what [Firebase Version 6.18.0 released on February 25, 2020](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios?hl=en#fcm_14) says:

> Deprecated FCM direct channel messaging via shouldEstablishDirectChannel. Instead, use APNs for downstream message delivery. Add content_available key to your payload if you want to continue use legacy APIs, but we strongly recommend HTTP v1 API as it provides full APNs support. The deprecated API will be removed in Firebase 7

This change was [merged](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/4710) on February 18, 2020.